# If I select first checkbox then disable all remaining checkboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, checkbox

I have four check boxes inside a separate label.

If I select **first** check box then all remaining check boxes will be disable.  If I click **first** again, all check boxes will be enabled.
If I select any other check box, the others are still enabled: I can select more than one. [See image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DwNdO.jpg)

How can I set this up?

Comment: May you post what you tried so far ?

Comment: [Minimal, verifiable sample](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is required here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

HTML:

```
<label for="one"><input type="checkbox" name="one" id="one"></label>
<label for="two"><input type="checkbox" name="two" id="two"></label>
<label for="three"><input type="checkbox" name="three" id="three"></label>
<label for="four"><input type="checkbox" name="four" id="four"></label>
```

jQuery:

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').on('change', function() {
    if($('input[type="checkbox"]').eq(0).is(':checked')){
        $('input[type="checkbox"]').not($(this)).attr('disabled', true);
    }
    else{
        $('input[type="checkbox"]').not($(this)).attr('disabled', false);
    }
});
```

Working example: https://jsfiddle.net/e26vnnk2/

Comment: Thanks! Its Working. Please i want another help, In addition suppose i also have drop down(select) list there is five value{1,2,3,4,5} if i select 1 then remaining checkbox(2,3,4) will be disable and again select 1  then all checkbox will be enable.

Comment: @UDigi Check this out https://jsfiddle.net/e26vnnk2/1/ Please vote this answer up.

Comment: Hi Reza,  dropdown list also part of above question.

Comment: dropdown list has 7 days and checkbox has four period (24hrs, morning, afternoon, evening). if i select 1 day above value then morning, afternoon, evening will be disabled.

Comment: @UDigi I think it would be better if you can show me the problem with some images.

Comment: ! Please see the image. [![Untitled-1.png](https://s3.postimg.org/70m9h05pf/Untitled_1.png)](https://postimg.org/image/ueu8sxnmn/)

Comment: @UDigi Ok, I see. Is it possible for you to ask a new question about this and send the link for me? I'll post the answer for you there. Please add all the details, because other users have to understand the main problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking in order to find out how to disable all other "checkboxes," use radiogroups. If you are saying that the first checkbox auto-triggers a toggle on the other checkboxes, try ungrouping them, or making them separate in and of themselves, because it sounds as if you have some kind of faulty grouping and dependency there.